# My Actor is being drawn right, but its bounds moves wrong

Tags: libgdx, kotlin

I have an `Actor` that is a circle drawn by `ShapeRenderer`, but when I drag it, its bounds moves wrong.

[before dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9Ph7.png)

[while dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPsLB.png)

And the scale of its bounds (green debug line) is also wrong. I think it caused by the incorrect transformation matrices between `Batch` ad `ShapeRenderer` but not sure how to fix it.

Main class:

```
class Main : ApplicationAdapter() {

lateinit var stage: Stage
lateinit var sr: ShapeRenderer
lateinit var bubble: Bubble

override fun create() {
    stage = Stage(ExtendViewport(800f,500f))
    sr = ShapeRenderer()
    Gdx.input.inputProcessor = stage
    bubble = Bubble(sr)
    bubble.debug = true
    stage.addActor(bubble)
}

override fun render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    stage.act()
    stage.draw()
}

override fun resize(width: Int, height: Int) {
    stage.viewport.update(width,height,true)
}

override fun dispose() {
    sr.dispose()
    stage.dispose()
}
}
```

Actor's class:

```
class Bubble(val sr: ShapeRenderer) : Actor() {

val defaultRadius: Float = 50f
var xPos: Float = 0f
var yPos: Float = 0f
var radius: Float = defaultRadius

init {
    addListener(object: InputListener() {
        override fun touchDown(event: InputEvent?, x: Float, y: Float, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
            radius = defaultRadius * 1.2f
            return true
        }

        override fun touchUp(event: InputEvent?, x: Float, y: Float, pointer: Int, button: Int) {
            radius = defaultRadius / 1.2f
        }

        override fun touchDragged(event: InputEvent?, x: Float, y: Float, pointer: Int) {
            xPos = x
            yPos = y
        }
    })
}

override fun act(delta: Float) {
    setBounds(xPos,yPos,radius*2,radius*2)
}

override fun draw(batch: Batch?, parentAlpha: Float) {
    batch!!.end()

    sr.projectionMatrix = batch.projectionMatrix
    sr.transformMatrix = batch.transformMatrix
    sr.translate(x, y, 0f)

    sr.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled)
    sr.color = Color.RED
    sr.circle(xPos, yPos, radius)
    sr.end()

    batch.begin()
}
}
```